# Convolution with one of the variables is mixed and the other continuous

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, convolution

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with CDF $F$ and $G$ and nonnegative support.

If $X$ has a point mass $p$ at $0$ and otherwise some "density" $f$ (that is, $\Pr(0<X<a)=\int_0^af(x)dx$) and $Y$ has density $g$. Define $Z=X+Y$. In the context I'm reading $Z$ has a density $h$. I find this counter intuitive because I would think that the "bump" of size $p$ at $0$ from $X$ would probably contribute to some sort of bump for $Z$. Can you please provide an explanation / intuition?

Because of the uncertainty, I'm also struggling to find $h$. I think that for $z>0$, I simply have
$$
h(z)=\int_0^zf(x)g(z-x)dx
$$
and $h(0)=pg(0)=0$. But there are probably some errors. I have seen these links [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) [[2]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593366/convolution-of-continuous-and-discrete-distributions) but I don't think they cover my situation. I would appreciate a self-contained reference (book, article, anything) if you know a good one. Thanks.

**Edit**: for the intuition part, I've just realized it: in order to have $Z=0$, both $X$ and $Y$ have to be $0$. The former happens with probability $p$ while the latter happens with probability $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point mass at $0$ contributes an impulse of area p to the pdf $f_X(x)$.

$$f_X(x) = p\delta(x) + f(x)$$

where f(x) is the part of $f_X(x)$ on (0,a].  When you convolve g with that impulse, you get a copy of g back multiplied by p. That adds on to the convolution of the rest of f with g since convolution is linear.

$$h(z) = \int_0^{\infty}[p\delta(x) + f(x)]g(z-x)dx$$

$$= pg(z) + \int_0^{\infty}f(x)g(z-x)dx.$$

Picture g being first flipped with respect to $0$, and then sliding to the right past the delta function.  The value of g(0) will get multiplied by the delta function and integrated to produce the value pg(z) at z=0, and every value of g(x) will get scaled and become pg(z) for z = x as it slides along.

If the point mass had been some other x = a, it would have the effect of shifting g to the right by a (left for negative a), and multiplied by p.

$$\int_0^{\infty}[p\delta(x-a)g(z-x)]dx = pg(z-a)$$

I understand certain mathematicians hate the following notation, but it really helps to understand what's going on, which is why it's used in signal processing:

$$g(x)*p\delta(x) = pg(x)$$

$$g(x)*p\delta(x-a) = pg(x-a)$$

$$[p\delta(x)+f(x)]*g(x) = pg(x) + f(x)*g(x)$$

The first is an ideal transmission with scaling, and the second is an ideal delay with scaling.