# PDF for $\xi + \eta$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function

Let $\xi $ and $ \eta$ be independent random  variables, $\xi$ is $U[0,1]$ , $\eta$ takes values $1/3$ and $2/3$ with probability $1/2$.
Find the PDF for $\xi + \eta$

It is easy for two continuous random variables, but what should I do in this situation?

Comment: Consider the CDF of $\xi + \eta$, i.e. $\Pr\{\xi + \eta \leq x\}$, then apply the law of total probability with condition on $\eta$

Comment: You may find this post helpful as well (the convolution of a discrete and continuous random variable): 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593366/convolution-of-continuous-and-discrete-distributions

Answer (score 1):

**Preliminary Lemma:** if $f$ is a pdf, $$f(x)*\delta_a(x)=f(x-a).$$

Proof: Let $X$ a random variable with pdf $f$ and $Y=a$ (constant), thus with pdf $\delta_a$, ("a probability peak of value 1 concentrated in position $a$"). Then the pdf of random variable $X+Y=X+a$, which is clearly the shifted version: $x\mapsto f(x-a)$, is  besides, the pdf of a sum of random variables, thus the convolution of the associated pdfs.

---

The pdf of Random Variable $X$ is $\Pi_{[0,1]}$, the characteristic function of interval $[0,1]$.

The pdf of Random Variable $Y$ is $\frac12(\delta_{1/3}+\delta_{2/3})$.

The pdf of $X+Y$ is the convolution:

$$g=\Pi_{[0,1]} * \frac12(\delta_{1/3}+\delta_{2/3})$$

By distributivity property:

$$g=\frac12\Pi_{[0,1]} * \delta_{1/3}+\frac12\Pi_{[0,1]} * \delta_{2/3}$$

Using the Lemma, one can write:

$$g=\frac12\Pi_{[1/3,4/3]}+\frac12\Pi_{[2/3,5/3]}$$

which can be also written:

$$g=\frac12\Pi_{[1/3,2/3]}+\Pi_{[2/3,4/3]}+\frac12\Pi_{[4/3,5/3]}$$

The graphical representation of this pdf is:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**Comment:** Here is a simulation in R statistical software that may help you verify the answer when
you get it. I used $X \sim Unif(0,1)$ and $Y$ taking values $1/3$ and $2/3$
each with probability $1/2,$ and $S = X + Y.$ With a million realizations
of each random variable simulated means and SDs should be accurate to about
three places.

```
m = 10^6;  x = runif(m)
y = sample(c(1/3,2/3), m, repl=T)
s = x + y
cut = seq(1/3, 5/3, 1/18)
hist(s, prob=T, br=cut, col="wheat")
mean(x); mean(y);  mean(s)
## 0.4995831      # aprx E(X) = 1/2
## 0.500128       # aprx E(Y) = 1/2
$$ 0.9997111      # aprx E(S) = 1
sd(x); sd(y); sd(s)
## 0.28881
## 0.1666667
## 0.3337064
summary(s)
##    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
##  0.3333  0.7492  0.9993  0.9997  1.2500  1.6670
quantile(s, (1:6)/6)
## 16.66667% 33.33333%       50% 66.66667% 83.33333%      100% 
## 0.6659555 0.8329647 0.9993092 1.1662825 1.3340041 1.6666663
```

You can view this as a 50:50 mixture of two uniform distributions,
one of them on the interval $(1/3, 4/3).$

[image]

Comment: "You can view this as a 50:50 mixture of two uniform distributions, one of them on the interval (1/3,5/3)." You might have meant 'one of them on the interval (1/3,4/3)".

Comment: @Did, Right, Typo. Sorry. Fixed.

Comment: Since you are here... how comes you are repeatedly posting as answers, texts that are not answers? As you say yourself here, simulations of homework problems can help *check* their solutions -- but this is not the stuff answers should be made of, is it?

Comment: When there is little engagement by OP, I prefer to provide, hints and visualizations, and try to _teach_ something at an appropriate level, without providing a post that can just be turned in as hwk without any thought. Sometimes the hints take the form of formulas or simulations, for which I find the official Comment format unworkable. Also, I have a few indications the simulations have been useful to others. (Another less frequent reason for some of my simulations is to try to settle which of conflicting answers is right, or to challenge an answer I think is wrong.)

Comment: Hints are all right with me, as is your proclaimed desire to teach maths rather than to provide full-blown solutions ready to be handed in. The trouble with the posts I am alluding to, and the present one is an example, is that they are neither providing a hint of the proof nor teaching any maths, at most they show how to use R and they provide an indication of the final answer. How is the OP supposed to turn this into a true math answer? Your desire to contribute to **math**.SE not knowing the relevant **mathematics**, is laudable, I guess, but it leads you to post numerous offtopic answers.

Comment: Oh, and when you think there is too little "engagement by the OP", a proper reaction is to *vote to close*, rather than deliberately posting an offtopic answer to a question without context.